# how to use button click indrowp don list in angular

Tags: angular

i want use a buttom click in drowpdon list in angular

html

```
<select style="width:200px; margin-right: 10%;" dir="rtl" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
      <option> لطفا نوع ساز زا انتخاب نمایید</option>
      <option *ngFor="let item of type; let i = index" (click)="test(item.id)">{{item.name}}</option>

    </select>
```

angular

```
test(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using (change) instead of (click) like so:

```
    <select (change)="test($event.target.value)" style="width:200px; margin-right: 10%;" dir="rtl" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
          <option> لطفا نوع ساز زا انتخاب نمایید</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of type; let i = index" >{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

move the click to select and use ngModel

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" (click)="test(selectedVal.id)" style="width:200px; margin-right: 10%;" dir="rtl" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
  <option> لطفا نوع ساز زا انتخاب نمایید</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of type; let i = index" >{{item.name}}</option>

</select>
```